# What's the difference between stage video and spark video display?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm a little confused on the terms.  I understand that the spark framework has a video player and a video display.  The difference being that video display doesn't have the video controls.

I know that stage video is new in AIR3 and uses hardware acceleration to play videos.

My question is, does videodisplay and videoplayer take advantage of stage video out of the box?  Do I need to implement it another way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any references to it within VideoDisplay and I don't see anything in VideoPlayer regarding StageVideo, plus from reading this article it sounds to me like they would keep them as two completely separate beasts, due to the possibility that the GPU is already in use and therefore can't be used at any given point in time (just what it sounds like to me). http://corlan.org/2010/12/01/working-with-stage-video/

Also when I Ctrl+Shift+T to get to VideoDisplay and VideoPlayer it specifically notes that they aren't optimized for mobile, which it seems is the main purpose for the new class (it's built in to the flash player it seems so I can't access the source).

If you're looking for something with pre-packaged controls and that can take advantage of the new StageVideo, check out the open source media framework (OSMF) says they support it in versions > 1.6.  http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.adobe.com%2Fosmf%2F2011%2F02%2Fgetting-started-with-stage-video-support-in-osmf-and-strobe-media-playback.html&ei=gbo6T46qKIyXtwedwonzCg&usg=AFQjCNHpm7AV9MZHw79TZjAs_nIZc-qoow&sig2=45WDlwOlB60uMzivf1fZOw

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research StageVideo for AIR desktop and extended desktop profiles is not available.

There seems to be an announcement about AIR in the coming days.  Hopefully they put this on the road map.  Some adobe guys hinted that this is coming.